# Custom taxonomy with custom post type archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, metabox, custom-post-type-archives

I created a sustom taxonomy and a custom post type via Metabox plugin.

I am able to create custom post type posts and assign them to the custom taxonomies.

But when I am trying to list them on an archive page like site.com/post-type/custom-taxonomy there is only the 404-template showing up.

Can you help me?

This is my custom post type function:

```
function portfolio_post_type() {

$args = array (
    'label' => esc_html__( 'Buchgestaltungen', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
    'labels' => array(
        'menu_name' => esc_html__( 'Buchgestaltungen', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => esc_html__( 'Buchgestaltung', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'add_new' => esc_html__( 'Add new', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'add_new_item' => esc_html__( 'Add new Buchgestaltung', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'new_item' => esc_html__( 'New Buchgestaltung', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'edit_item' => esc_html__( 'Edit Buchgestaltung', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'view_item' => esc_html__( 'View Buchgestaltung', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'update_item' => esc_html__( 'Update Buchgestaltung', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'all_items' => esc_html__( 'All Buchgestaltungen', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'search_items' => esc_html__( 'Search Buchgestaltungen', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => esc_html__( 'Parent Buchgestaltung', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'not_found' => esc_html__( 'No Buchgestaltungen found', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => esc_html__( 'No Buchgestaltungen found in Trash', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Buchgestaltungen', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
        'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Buchgestaltung', 'portfolio-post-type' ),
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-arrow-right-alt2',
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'thumbnail',
        'custom-fields',
        'revisions',
    ),
    'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => false,
    ),
);

register_post_type( 'buchgestaltung', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_post_type' );
```

This is my custom taxonomy function:

```
function buchgestaltungskategorie() {

$args = array (
    'label' => esc_html__( 'Buchgestaltungskategorien', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
    'labels' => array(
        'menu_name' => esc_html__( 'Buchgestaltungskategorien', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'all_items' => esc_html__( 'All Buchgestaltungskategorien', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'edit_item' => esc_html__( 'Edit Buchgestaltungskategorie', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'view_item' => esc_html__( 'View Buchgestaltungskategorie', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'update_item' => esc_html__( 'Update Buchgestaltungskategorie', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'add_new_item' => esc_html__( 'Add new Buchgestaltungskategorie', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'new_item_name' => esc_html__( 'New Buchgestaltungskategorie', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'parent_item' => esc_html__( 'Parent Buchgestaltungskategorie', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => esc_html__( 'Parent Buchgestaltungskategorie:', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'search_items' => esc_html__( 'Search Buchgestaltungskategorien', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'popular_items' => esc_html__( 'Popular Buchgestaltungskategorien', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => esc_html__( 'Separate Buchgestaltungskategorien with commas', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => esc_html__( 'Add or remove Buchgestaltungskategorien', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => esc_html__( 'Choose most used Buchgestaltungskategorien', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'not_found' => esc_html__( 'No Buchgestaltungskategorien found', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Buchgestaltungskategorien', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
        'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Buchgestaltungskategorie', 'buchgestaltungskategorie' ),
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'sort' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'buchgestaltung',
        'with_front' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'buchgestaltungskategorie', array( 'buchgestaltung' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'buchgestaltungskategorie', 0 );
```

The way I like to acces the archive page is site.com/buchgestaltung/start
This page should list all posts which have the custom taxonomy 'start' assigned.

Can you tell me, why this is not working?

Lukas

Answer (score 0):

## solved

The rewrite slug of the custom taxonomy was somewhere competing with the corresponding custom post type slug. Afterwards I added a normal loop to the archives.php template. That made the trick.